# <a href, click not working on single click

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am having a bit of a problem with my code.
I have a small window in my asp.net webform in which I create a table.
In the table I have this line.

```html
<td style=\"font-size: 11px;text-align: left;\">" + ("<a style=\"color: black;\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"WidgetOpenSMV('" + (t.CompanyId) + "');\">" + (t.CompanyName) + "</a>") + "</td>"
```

In my .js file i have this function:

```html
function WidgetOpenSMV(companyId) {
    windowManager.CreateWindow('SMVContactsEdit.aspx?companyId=' + companyId);
}
```

My problem that it rarely works with one click.
But when I doubleclick it calls the functions twice and creates two windows.

I cannot figure out why it behaves like that?
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure out what is happening exactly in such cases is to use your [browser's built-in developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint) and place a breakpoint in the function that you expect to be called.

If the execution doesn't pause there on first click, but does so on the second, you know something's wrong with how the click event gets attached to your link element.

If you get a pause on first click but the window doesn't get opened, you know the issue is with your window manager.

Comment: If I insert a debugger command like this.

    debugger;
    windowManager.CreateWindow('SMVContactsEdit.aspx?companyId=' + companyId);

It does not break on single click, but it only breaks once on double click.
Now I am more confused.

Comment: That is pretty confusing indeed. When I try this [in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-dust-s0j24?file=/index.html) it works as one might expect. Try inspecting the clickable element and look at the event that's attached. It could be that there's multiple handlers which are interfering.

Comment: Maybe it is because my html code is created and send with response.write.

Comment: Swapping onclick with onmousedown seems to do the trick.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but always a bit irritating when one can't figure out why the simple method that should work does not. Good luck.